# How to transfer files between the pods in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, docker-registry

I want to transfer my files generated by one of the pod of my application to the Kubernetes cronjob pod.
Is there any method to transfer files between the two pods of a cluster?

Comment: What have you tried up untill now ?

Comment: Standard practice is to use well-defined APIs, so have the one pod send something like an HTTP request to the other.  Don't try to share files.

Comment: What are You trying to achieve? Are You trying to make one way file transfer or read-write for both pods?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [`persistent-volume`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) and mount the same volume to both the containers

Comment: (Requires backing storage that allows ReadWriteMany access mode, which may not be available in your environment.)

Comment: @DavidMaze isn´t your claim only true if you want to persists between different nodes?

Comment: I guess, but I'd be surprised to see Kubernetes somewhere that wasn't a multi-node environment (or planned to be in production).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hostdir` if you don't want to persist data. however, you can use PVC and any type of shared volume to store data which can be accessible by both pods cronjobs & pod.

Comment: A host-path volume will silently fail if the two pods aren't on the same node, and in a cloud environment where nodes can be automatically removed, it's highly likely to remove data.  I would not recommend this.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes you are absolutely right i do agree with you however if he wanted to run pod can add `affinity` or `node selector`. obviously having PVC would be a better option but pvc require `ReadWriteMany`.